# Error calling oracle StoredProcedure with Spring

Tags: java, spring, oracle, stored-procedures

I have an oracle Stored Procedure which i can't change or code. The Procedure receives the following I/O

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SCHEMA"."NAMEPROCEDURE"
            (
                ZCLIENTE_IN     IN  CHAR,
                CKBALCAO_IN     IN  CHAR,
                NRPROCES_IN     IN  NUMBER,
                DTINICIO_IN     IN  CHAR,
                DTFIM_IN        IN  CHAR,
                TPDOCUME_IN     IN  CHAR,
                EMAIL_IN        IN  CHAR,
                OK_KO_OUT       OUT CHAR,
                MSGERR_OUT      OUT VARCHAR2
            )
IS
PROXNUM     CHAR(14);

BEGIN ...
```

...

This procedure inserts my Input in some tables.
In a springBoot application i am trying to call it with the following repository code:

```
 String procedureName = "NAMEPROCEDURE";
String catalogName = "SCHEMA";


String okKo ="";
String msgErro ="";

simpleJdbcCall.withCatalogName(catalogName).withProcedureName(procedureName)
.declareParameters(new SqlOutParameter("OK_KO_OUT", OracleTypes.CHAR), new SqlOutParameter("MSGERR", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
      new SqlInOutParameter("ZCLIENTE_IN", OracleTypes.CHAR), 
      new SqlInOutParameter("CKBALCAO_IN", OracleTypes.CHAR),
      new SqlInOutParameter("NRPROCES_IN", OracleTypes.NUMBER),
      new SqlInOutParameter("DTINICIO_IN", OracleTypes.CHAR),
      new SqlInOutParameter("DTFIM_IN", OracleTypes.CHAR),
      new SqlInOutParameter("TPDOCUME_IN", OracleTypes.CHAR),
      new SqlInOutParameter("EMAIL_IN", OracleTypes.CHAR)
    );
MapSqlParameterSource inParams = new MapSqlParameterSource();
inParams.addValue("ZCLIENTE_IN", "1111111111", OracleTypes.CHAR);
inParams.addValue("CKBALCAO_IN", "0000", OracleTypes.CHAR);
inParams.addValue("NRPROCES_IN", 20160000001L, OracleTypes.BIGINT);
inParams.addValue("DTINICIO_IN", "2016-01-01", OracleTypes.CHAR);
inParams.addValue("DTFIM_IN", "2019-01-01", OracleTypes.CHAR);
inParams.addValue("TPDOCUME_IN", "0011", OracleTypes.CHAR);
inParams.addValue("EMAIL_IN", "someEmail@gmail.com", OracleTypes.CHAR);

Map<String, Object> simpleJdbcCallResult =  simpleJdbcCall.execute(inParams);
```

But i am receiving the follwoing log error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
>   CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call
>   SCHEMA.NAMEPROCEDURE()}]; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 7: PLS-00306: número
>   errado ou tipos de argumentos na chamada para
>   'PROCEDURENAME' ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 7:~
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 7:
>   PLS-00306: número errado ou tipos de argumentos na chamada para
>   'PROCEDURENAME' ORA-06550: linha 1, coluna 7: PL/SQL:
>   Statement ignored
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
>   ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)
>   ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1059)
>   ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:522)
>   ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
>   ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]     at
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
>   ~[ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.jar:12.1.0.2.0]

I have no idea of what am i doing wrong, because if i have the same call with just 2 arguments and returning a Cursor it works perfectly.

Tks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer for anyone who's having the same problem.
In my Pom.xml I had ojdbc7 driver and need to have ojbdc6. Heres de dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
   <version>11.2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

No idea why but it worked for me. There must be some incompatibility between SQL- call function and oracle.

Comment: Chech the [JDBC Compatibility Matrix](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_01) to see, which Java, Oracle and JDBC Driver Versions are compatible ....